# Query to mySQL not always calling latest data

Tags: jquery, mysql, node.js

Really searched for this answer but perhaps the way I phrase it is incorrect. I am using node and mySQL. I have a client screen. I click the Edit / View button.

[image: start]

The edit screen comes up.

[image: edit screen]

I then edit the client, in this case the first name and submit.

[image: edit first name]

When I submit I see the change on the main client ul where I can see the first name has been changed.

[image: after edit]

When I press the Edit / View button again I cannot see my change however it is definately in the database.

[image: re enter edit]

If I navigate to a completely different view, I can see the change has been effected.

[image: same client different view]

If I navigate back to the client view and press the Edit / View button it is not showing.

[image: return to edit client]

I cannot fathom what I am doing wrong. It works fine on my localhost and local DB.

my routes.

```
var clientReturned;
router.get('/getclient/:clientID', function(req, res){
  client = req.params.clientID;
  var sql = `select cl.id, cl.first_name, cl.last_name, 
             cl.email, cl.client_type, ct.client_type_description, 
             cl.active, cl.activity_reason from clients cl 
             inner join client_type  ct on ct.id = cl.client_type
             where cl.id = ${client}`;
  connection.query(sql, function (error, results, fields) {
    if (error) throw error;
    clientReturned = results;
    console.log(clientReturned);
    res.send({ clientReturned: clientReturned }); 
  });
});

router.post('/editClient', function(req, res){
  var client = {
      last_name: req.body.lastName,
      first_name: req.body.firstName,
      email: req.body.email,
      active: req.body.activity,
      activity_reason: req.body.activityReason,
      client_type: req.body.clientType
  } 
  var id = req.body.id;
  console.log(client);
  connection.query(`UPDATE clients SET ? where ID = ${id}`,client, function (error, result) {
    if (error) throw error;
    res.redirect('/clients');  
 });
});
```

Client-side:

```
var clientID;

$('#clientData').on("click",".edit-btn",function(e){
    clientID = $(this).attr('id');
        e.preventDefault();
        var x = (screen.width);
        var y = (screen.height)
        var swidth = (screen.width) * .6; 
        var sheight = (screen.height) * .6;
        var newTop = (y - sheight)/2;
        var newLeft = (x - swidth)/2;
        var newMargin = (swidth - 300)/2;
        $(".lightbox1").fadeIn().css("width", x).css("height", y);
        $(".lightboxA1").css("width",swidth).css("height", sheight).css("top", newTop).css("left", newLeft);
        $('.lightboxA1').fadeIn().css("display", "flex").css("align-items", "center").css("align-content", "space-around");
        $(".inputData1").css("margin-left", newMargin);
        editData = [];//clears edit query
        clientType = [];
        clearClientType();
        $('.inputDataFields1 > select').css({"color": "red"});
        $('#editClientType').empty();
        var url = '/getclient/' + clientID;
        var url2 = '/getClientTypes';
        $.get(url, function(data){  
            editData = data.clientReturned;   
        }).then(function(){
            $.get(url2, function(data){  
                clientTypes = data;   
            }).then(function(){
                fillEditInputs();
                console.log("Success");
            }).catch(function(){
                console.log("Some Issue Here");
            });
        });       
    });


var editData = [];//clears edit query
var clientTypes = [];//clears clientType

function clearClientType() {
    $('#editClientType').empty();
}


function fillEditInputs() {  
    clientTypes.forEach(function(clientType){
            val = clientType.id
            const text = clientType.client_type_description;
            $(`<option value="${val}">${text}</option>`).appendTo('#editClientType');
    });

    $("#client-id").val(editData[0].id);
    $("#editLastName").val(editData[0].last_name);
    $("#editFirstName").val(editData[0].first_name);
    $("#editEmail").val(editData[0].email);
    $('#editClientType').val(editData[0].client_type);
    if (editData[0].active === 1) {
    $("#activeChecked1").prop("checked", true);
    $("#isActive").val(1)
    $("#activeChecked1").val(1);
    $("#inactivityReason").css("display", "none");
    $("#inactivityReasonLabel").css("display", "none"); 
    } else {
    $("#activeChecked1").prop("checked", false);
    $("#activeChecked1").val(0);
    $("#isActive").val(0)
    $("#inactivityReason").val(editData[0].activity_reason);
    }

}
```

Comment: If you can show your client code we might be able to help. I suspect its the issue on client code and not on server side.Is this a single page application ??

Comment: try to clear the modal after submitting `$('#myModal form :input').val("");`

Comment: I have added it above.

Comment: Where would I clear the modal after submitting?

Comment: Clearing modal form after submit not working

Comment: You should clear "editData" variable in fillEditInnput function at the end. Because it is cleared only once the page is loaded. Try clearing that variable.Clear clientTypes.

Comment: @Mukesh Verma - Unfortunately clearing the editData and clientTypes variables still is not working

Comment: The problem definately appears to be server side in the route. If I console.log(editData) or console.log(data.clientReturned) it shows an array without the effected changes. I am at a bit of a loss.

Comment: The data changes immedietly in the database but it seems to delay coming back to the same view? Almost as if cached

Comment: Just a thought, basically the updated data is not coming through straight away. It is posting to the database and if you use a different view you can immediately see the changes. But in the view you do not see the changes for a while. I am really not sure why. Why would a select statement not show the very latest changes that are in the database? Is there a way to effectively refresh that database from the app (close and then open the connection? Is this a viable solution?)